# Insert many key=>value pairs in array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I have several identical forms on a page (it's for rating stuff). The form looks like this:

```
    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">

    <input  id="titel" name="titel">
    <textarea id="msg" name="comment" class="txtarea"></textarea>

    <button id="send">Send</button>
     </form>
```

I'm sending the form data via ajax to a page where I want to store all the key=>value pairs in an array.

This is what I have on my php page where the form data is sent:

```
$arr = $_POST; 

$array = array();

$array['titel'] = $arr['titel'];
$array['comment'] = $arr['comment'];

print_r($array);
```

When I send the first form prin_r gives:
      Array ( [titel] => test [comment] => test2 )

Which is exactly what I want. But when I send the next form the values ar not inserted in the array, like:

```
    Array ( [titel] => test [comment] => test2
    [titel] => test3 [comment] => test4

 )
```

In fact nothing happens. The values remain the same.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: you can't have same keys in array

Comment: Each time you submit a form, the PHP script is starting fresh, it doesn't have any memory of the previous use (unless you save it in session data).

Comment: So, is it not possible to create an associative array with 
key1=>value1, key2=>value2,
key1=>value3, key2=>value4....
Like when you iterate over the columns of a db?

Comment: those would be a multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly wrapping up the comments here.

**1. Forms and request isolation**

You said you submit several forms. Each time you submit form data to a PHP script, the script is executed line by line and when done, the whole process is terminated. When submitting another form, this will be another script execution which has none of the variables available you defined earlier.

This is how HTTP works. Each request is an isolated execution.

One technique to "remember" data bound to a specific client is to create a session.
A session consists of an id, which is stored on the client side, by default automatically into a cookie, and the session storage, which is saved on the server and can be reused over several isolated requests.

Learn more here
http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

**2. Arrays in PHP**

Array keys have to be unique.
Imagine - how PHP should know, which value you want to access if that would not be a unique constraint.

You said "array like several rows of a database result"

This looks like this

```
$result = array
(
    0 => array ( 'col1' => 'colval1' ),
    1 => array ( 'col1' => 'vol1val' )
)
```

You can do the same

```
$survey = array (
    'step1' => array(...)
);
```

Access like this

```
$survey['step1']['..']
```

To save this into a session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['step1'] = $survey['step1'];
```

To access this in a later request

```
print_r( $_SESSION['step1'] );
```

Hope this helps :)
Merry Christmas

Comment: Excellent, I knew my method was wrong, but I couldn't quite figure out why and how to get it right. Your answer clarifies this! Many thanks and merry christmas to you too!